# Big M method and keeping the constraints minimized

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Problem:

Using the Big M method and keeping the constraints minimized how would I solve this:

Minimize:

$-2x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4$

Subject to:

$$
\begin{align}
x_1+2x_2+2x_3+x_4 \leq 2\\
x_1-2x_2+x_3+2x_4\geq3\\
2x_1-x_2+3x_3\geq2\\
x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \geq 0\\
\end{align}$$

I need help solving it though the Big M method. I keep getting stuck and need to figure out if my pivots are working instead of cycling.

Thanks in advance.